# How to allow user to input in a editText only once and disable it after that?

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

How can i allow a user to input in a editText only once (maximum of 3 times is desirable). After that the editText must be locked or disabled. For example suppose a user enters his username in the Profile section. And if he press the save button the username editText should be locked/disabled.

How can i do this.Please help

NOTE: I have written allow user to input olny once but 3 times is desirable (in case user make some mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to store if the user has used the editText the way you wanted and once you have done that, simply use: `editText.setEnabled(false)` or `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)`
OR better:
`editText.setFocusable(false)`
One of these should work and then user will be able to see the editText but not type anything.